# Flopping toy mechanism design

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, servo

I've bought a flopping toy for my kid. The toy looks like:

[image]

Unfortunately, the toy mechanism inside jams when grabbed and the battery lasts for a short time:

[image: Mechanism]

I tried to do my own mechanism, printing own case and using Arduino with servo PowerHD R12 but the servo was heating up :( Is there any possibility to make similar mechanism for toy with not oversizing it? What kind of motor/mechanism would be good for that kind of sweeping toy so it doesn't get hot?

Comment: Consider adding a bit more detail in your post. It could help people provide a better answer.

Comment: Try a servo saver or spring.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the motor will be heating up when it reaches a "hard limit". At that point it still tries to move (but it can't) and draws too much current while it tries to move.

I would start by trying to limit the range of the motion of the servo motor. If the motion does not hit a hard barrier, then you just might be ok, without reprinting everything.